# Subsetting data.table columns using []

Tags: r, data.table, subset

This is very strange. When I try to select columns on my `data.table` by doing

```
df1[, 30]
```

It just gives me 30, or whatever number I put in there. Not column 30.

Data here: https://github.com/pourque/country-data/blob/master/data/df1.csv

I've checked, and everything works properly when I just produce a test `data.frame`:

```
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 3:1, z = 7:9)
> df2[, 2]
[1] 3 2 1
```

Any ideas on what might be happening?

Comment: data frame or a data table? the behavior you described looks like a data table one.

Comment: My bad, it is a data table. I'll convert it into a data frame and hopefully that will fix this!

Comment: Just ignore my comment.  I thought you want it as a column.  If it is a data.table, `df2[,2, with=FALSE]`

Comment: For reference, it's the first question in the faq :) https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf You may want to edit the question title (since it says "data frame")

Comment: Oh...well this is embarrassing. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When working with data.table you need to use following to chose column by numbers:

```
df2[, 2]
df2[, .SD, .SDcols=2]
```

This will still return data.table, not a vector.
As always on list you can also use below to return a vector:

```
df2[[2]]
```